# Facebook Explorer page showing BLANK page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When I try to visit this url https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/

Its shows complete blank page.

I tried with different browser. I tried with different internet connection.  I trie on PC and phone.

All Same

What could be the reason?  Am I blocked from using the explorer?

Answer (score 0):

Try [this link](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895?method=GET&path=145634995501895&version=v2.1)

Press the button "Get Accces Token", "Get Access Token" again in the pop-up window (you don't need special permissions there) and then "Submit" button.

Comment: Blank white page either :'(

Comment: Did you press the buttons like I said? After logging in to Facebook, and after pressing Get Access Token, does the Access Token field get automatically filled with something like  CAACEdEose0cBAJZASFSNzhYQbyzHLjETFyZAAiHizzbhVpdk2? If that is the case, the page information should appear after pressing Submit

Comment: Just after clicking the link above u specified. It simply show blank page. There is no button or anything to press :(

Comment: Are you logged in Facebook before clicking it? You should have joined Facebook as [Developer](https://developers.facebook.com/) with your normal account to see it. I can't think of anything else that could be wrong :/

Comment: Yeah i am logged in and I am already joinbed as Developer (I have 3 apps created and had been using API for years). It just suddenly happen that I can't access that specific page :S

Answer (score 0):

What I did to fix the blank page issue:

1. In the developer/app page, add product "Facebook Login for Business"
2. In the product settings page, switch to "Facebook Login"
3. Do not change any default settings to "Facebook Login"