# Facebook Graph API Explorer is showing a blank page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm following a tutorial related to data mining through Facebook, but I have stuck with a problem with Facebook Graph Api Exloper right at the beginning. I want to access a website https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer but all I get is a blank page. I'm logged on my FB account.

On SO I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26633607/facebook-explorer-page-showing-blank-page), which seems to be the same problem, but the answer there is not satisfying. 
I tried to use a different browser, as well as differently defined URL (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895?method=GET&path=145634995501895&version=v2.1) but it's all the same.

Does anyone know what is the reason?

Comment: Does going to https://developers.facebook.com/ work for you? Did you register your account as a developer already?

Comment: I think I'll contact them soon. I checked my flatmate's and my girlfriend's accounts have access to this site. however, neither of them is a developer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved, when I removed this application from the list of blocked applications